# Can SSD classify an image based on specific parts?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, object-detection

I was wondering if it is possible for SSD to classify an object based on its parts?

Like for example identifying a certain species using only its head and legs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes this is possible, but dependent on your training data. As can be seen on the left in this image, a human head can be detected and classified as `person`:

[image: Source: https://iamrobotandproud.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/05/29/015818]

Comment: Oooh nice. So like for example classifying the whole object based on the boxed parts?

Comment: Yes, but you have to create a custom labeled data set that either classifies the certain body parts separately or as the associated object.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question :) . Yeah me and my partner are collecting images for our dataset, we're planning on making a plant species classifier based on plant parts, and not just based on the whole plant image as input.